# calling PostToConnection to api gateway websocket [AccessDeniedException: code:403]

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

im trying to send message to websocket connection from lambda function but I get this error with no message from cloud watch

> AccessDeniedException: code:403

Im sure that the URL is correct but in API cloud watch group nothing printed out about what cause the problem
,my code:

```
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String(region),
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
conn := &connectionData{}
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(request.Body), conn)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
apigw := apigatewaymanagementapi.New(sess, &aws.Config{
    Endpoint: aws.String(conn.Callbackurl),
    Region:   aws.String(region),
    LogLevel: aws.LogLevel(aws.LogDebugWithEventStreamBody),
})
data, err := json.Marshal(fmt.Sprintf(`{"body":"Hi %s"}`, conn.ConnectionId))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
_, err = apigw.PostToConnection(&apigatewaymanagementapi.PostToConnectionInput{
    ConnectionId: aws.String(conn.ConnectionId),
    Data:         []byte(data),
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
return nil
```

I already authorized the lambda function with the API from the console

Comment: Does your Lambda role have the required permissions for `PostToConnection`?